# Core data to table view duplicates over two rows

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Trying out some core data stuff, nearly there but not quite.  Take this Simple table view with two`UILabels`.

The problem is this

[image]

Expected behaviour would be `abc` with `123` underneath on **one** row

Saving data

`var data = [NSManagedObject]()`

```
   func saveData(rowData: String) {

        //1 Get record
        let appDelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //Entity
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tasks", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)


        //3
        person.setValue(rowData, forKey: "engineerName")
        person.setValue(rowData, forKey: "projectDescription")


        //4
        var error: NSError?
        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
        //5
        data.append(person)


    }




    deinit {

        self.saveData(engineerField.text)
        self.saveData(currentProjectField.text)


    }
```

Loading it into Table view

`var data = [NSManagedObject]()`

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return data.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomRow") as! CustomRow

            //Get record from core data
            let person = data[indexPath.row]
             println("Row Data = \(person)")

            cell.nameLabel.text = person.valueForKey("engineerName") as? String
            cell.projectLabel.text = person.valueForKey("projectDescription") as? String


        return cell
    }
```

Core Data

[image]

Comment: what does `println("Row Data = \(person)")` print? I don´t see any problem here, it does exactly what I would expect, assuming your data in the DB is `((abc, abc), (123, 123))`

Comment: engineerName = abc;projectDescription = abc;  engineerName = 123; projectDescription = 123;

Comment: In your `saveData` method you are saving the same data for both `engineerName` and `projectDescription` NOT different data. You need to pass in two different strings (e.g. `engineerNameString` and `projectDescriptionString`) and save the different strings in your `person` managed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `saveData` method you are saving the same data for both `engineerName` and `projectDescription` *NOT* different data. You need to pass in two different strings (e.g. `engineerNameString` and `projectDescriptionString`) and save the different strings in your person managed object.

Example code based on your code:

```
func saveData(engineerNameString: String, projectDescriptionString: String) {

    //1 Get record
    let appDelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //Entity
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tasks", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    //3
    person.setValue(engineerNameString, forKey: "engineerName")
    person.setValue(projectDescriptionString, forKey: "projectDescription")

    //4
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    //5
    data.append(person)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is exactly what should happen. The visual duplication is there because you set the `cell.nameLabel.text` and `cell.projectLabel.text` and since internally `engineerName` and `projectDescription` contain the same value, both labels show the same data.

There still are only two cells, both displaying their relevant data.

You would have to store different data for `engineerName` and `projectDescription` - you will see that everything works as expected.